# Opsworks : Rails App Layer : specify Ruby minor version

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, version, aws-opsworks

I would like to pin my opsworks rails layers to ruby version 2.1.2
The layers apparently, upgraded to 2.1.5 and now I can no longer deploy my app.

I attempted to remedy this by adding custom json to my stack like so:

```
"opsworks": {
       "ruby": {
              "full_version": "2.1.2"
        }
   }
```

I also attempted this:

```
"ruby": {
       "full_version": "2.1.2",
       "major_version": "2.1",
       "minor_version": "1"
   }
```

Error message from deploy failure:

```
[2014-12-18T22:36:58+00:00] INFO: Running queued delayed notifications before re-raising exception
[2014-12-18T22:36:58+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2014-12-18T22:36:58+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2014-12-18T22:36:59+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/chef-stacktrace.out
[2014-12-18T22:36:59+00:00] ERROR: deploy[/srv/www/carlingo] (deploy::rails line 65) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '18'
---- Begin output of sudo su - deploy -c 'cd /srv/www/carlingo/releases/20141218223651 && /usr/local/bin/bundle install --path /home/deploy/.bundler/carlingo --without=test development' 2>&1 ----
STDOUT: Your Ruby version is 2.1.5, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.2
STDERR:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah ha, I picked up tips from some old doco I think.

By reading the [aws/opsworks code](https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/blob/9592158efa7fc0e265a4b0677f806f4dbf665995/ruby/recipes/default.rb#L41) I corrected my custom json to this:

```
"ruby": {
       "version": "2.1.2"
   }
```

and it worked!

Actually, this is only partially a correct answer.

I have one stack that responded to this and downgraded correctly and another stack that would not downgrade my ruby version, it reports this on "update_dependencies" and continues to fail on deploy.

```
Userspace Ruby version is up-to-date (2.1)
```

only my version when logged in is 2.1.5.

Many many re-deploys and update dependencies later eventually they all updated.

Answer (score 1):

Now it looks like the correct documentation is here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/attributes-json-opsworks-other.html#attributes-json-opsworks-ruby-version

This says to specify "opsworks": "ruby_version" and "ruby": "patch_version" like so:

```
{
  "opsworks": {
    "ruby_version": "2.2"
  },
  "ruby": {
    "patch_version": "3"
  }

}
```